# MVC 4 - Getting error while trying to add a new report

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, report

Followed the steps [within this link](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974), I succeeded to run a report using a DXperience ASP.Net MVC Web application project wizard, but when I tried to reproduce exactly the same thing using a basic ASP.Net MVC Web application project wizard, I got no debugger error while compiling, but the browser returned the the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the DevExpress extensions are visible in the namespace of your view.  Add a using, or add it to your Web.Config under ~/Views

```
@using Devexpress; // or whatever the namespace is
```

Also, you need to make sure that Devexpress is added as a reference to the project, if it's not already added.

Comment: At last it was a question of required assemblies: the Report and Reportviewer assemblies were missing in the web.config, as DevExpress doesn't add them automatically to the web.config as other controls.